# Are there any commentaries that refer to the word "Shanah" being an antagonym?

Tags: hebrew, rosh-hashanah-new-year, repentance-teshuvah

The Hebrew word שנה has several meanings. It means "year", "to review / repeat" (as it usage in the term,  משנה תורה and it also means "to change". Thus, it is an [antagonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym).

With Rosh Hashanna approaching, I'm curious if there are any commentaries or writings (ancient or more recent) that discuss these opposite meanings and how they may relate to the concept of Teshuva and how one should behave at the start of the new year.

For example, if one is to supposed to change his behavior, how does he do this by "repeating" it? Or, does the definition of "year" include both the concept of repetition as well as change and in what ways?

---

**Surmisal:** Every change involves repeating something from the past. The word "new" has several nuances, but, the main idea behind "new" is that it is something that previously never existed. Perhaps, this is the reason why Rosh Hodesh is not mentioned as part of Rosh Hashanna. "Hodesh" means "new". Perhaps, each month (except Rosh Hashanna), one should be creating something absolutely new. On Rosh Hashanna, we shouldn't create something "new" but, rather, we should change things by refining the past.

Comment: Interesting observation. Re terminology - is there a verb "shana" or "shina" that means both "repeat" and "change", or are those always distinct words? (I'm thinking of _l'shanos_ and its derivatives, which are usually in _pi'el_ in Hebrew, as opposed to _lishnos_ and friends, which are _pa'al_, while _l'shanen_ is _pi'el_.) Re etymology - are the roots for "year", "repeat" and "change" related?

Comment: @WAF *shanen* (as in *veshinantam lebanecha* is from a different root than *shanah*. As for the others, I believe that they all come from the same root s-n-h . The *binyan* shouldn't matter for purposes of this question. BTW, I think another meaning is "to learn" as in *shoneh kahalacha* (mentioned in Pirkei Avot), But, it may originate from *shanen*.

Comment: [This post](http://azrielariel.blogspot.com/2015/08/blog-post_79.html) made your observation too, but doesn't cite any sources.

Comment: I don't think there are opposite meaning here, it would seem they all boil down to meaning repeat/renew. The Hebrew word for tooth is שן which I'm guessing is because the old tooth falls out and then is renewed.

שנה - a *new* year; a *renewal* of the year
משנה תורה - a *review* of the Torah
שינון - to *review* one's learning
לשון - to *renew* oneself (by sleeping)
שן - a tooth, the only part of the human body the intentionally dies off and then *renews* itself

Comment: @DanF You wrote, '"Hodesh" means "new".' My comment: Does not Hodesh mean "Renewal" (that is not "absolutely new" but something that pre-exists that renews itself or that is renewed?), so that "Rosh Hodesh" means "Beginning of Renewal"?

Comment: @ninamag "Hodesh" comes from "Hadash" which means "new". There are nuances to what "new" means in Hebrew as well as in English (and, I gather in other languages, as well.) In English, we often see the term "newly improved." That implies taking an existing product, "improving" (usually by raising the price) it and then saying, "Hey, you've never seen it this way, before (with this price), so it's "new". (Stop laughing!!) Or, you see "brand new" meaning "It's never been around, before." My definition is my own analysis. Yours is absolutely acceptable, as well. We're both right!

Comment: @DanF Based on the definition provided in the link that you cite, שנה does not appear to be an antagonym. The definition states that within the multiple possible meanings of an antagonym, two of them must be the opposite of each other. Shanah as 'year', whether solar or lunar, refers to the repeating cycle of time corresponding with the solar orbit. The lunar year is also dependent on the solar orbit. There is no 'opposite' present. May you be sealed for a good & sweet year.

Comment: @DanF I thought "Shanah" was also the Hebrew root of the Yiddish word "Shaina", meaning beautiful; and "Shanah" is also the root word of the word to shine? Have you ever come across these? I have in the past, but it was in the context of linguistic, and not necessarily rabbinical.

Comment: @ninamag I'm not good with Yiddish etymology. But much of Yiddish comes from German. At any rate, in Yiddish "sheineh" means "beautiful" and, perhaps, may be more related to the English "shine" than it is to "shanah" in Hebrew. I'll see if I can find something on the Yiddish word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share with you this short teaching called "A Blessing for the New Year"
from Reb Zalman *z”l*.

"There is a paradox in the word שָׁנָה shanah, of Shanah Tovah and Rosh HaShanah. שָׁנָה Shanah in Hebrew carries two meanings. It has the sense of repeating, doing again a second time, sheini, and in this sense it is used in Mishnah, the laws repeated by heart, and also in the sense of which the fifth book of Moses is called Mishneh Torah, the repeating of the Torah (by Moses before his death). However it also has the sense of change, l’shanot, to make other – and here, too, is the sense of ‘two-ness,’ a second one that is different than the first.
    In Yiddish the same phrase with different inflections means the opposite.  היינט אזוי – מארגען אזוי  “Today like this; Tomorrow like this,”  can mean “Today like this > and also Tomorrow like this >” and it can mean “Today like this >”  (pointing to the right) and “Tomorrow like this <” (pointing to the left).
    It thus has the possibility of being read both ways: repeat or change. For those parts of your life that were good last year and that want to be repeated, I bless you with Shanah Tovah, have a good repeat. And for those things that need change, Shanah Tovah, have a good change!"

Comment: Reb Zalman who?

Comment: Probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zalman_Schachter-Shalomi?

Comment: Bounty awarded. Please specify per above comments. I have some questions as follow up which, B"N, I'll ask after YK.

Comment: Another year, another reminder :-) can you provide a link to the above or, specify who this "Reb Zalman" is?

Comment: @DanF WAF is most probably correct. This same piece is posted on the Aquarian Minyan's website http://www.aquarianminyan.org/arch61 and Schachter was a spiritual force of that cong.